# Python replace word with "word"

Tags: python, string, replace, quotes

How can I replace word with "word" in python?
I've already tried this:

```
str = "some_word"
str.replace("some_word", '"some_word"')
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: What are you trying do to? What is this for? Also, don’t name a variable `str`.

Comment: It DOES work. But remember that the `replace` method doesn't work inplace. Instead do `str = str.replace("some_word", '"some_word"')`

Comment: Also, try to check the difference between single and double quotes: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Don't use str as variable name as it is keyword in python.

```
d = 'ab'
print(d.replace('ab','ac'))
```

2) String are immutable in python so you have to re-assign it like:

```
d = d.replace('ab','ac')
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly works:

```
a = "some_word"
print(a) # some_word
a = a.replace("some_word", '"some_word"')
print(a) # "some_word"
```

If you want to wrap the *entire* string in double quotes, and not only a part of it, you may use one of these approaches:

```
a = "some_word"
a1 = '"{}"'.format(a)
a2 = '"' + a + '"'
a3 = f'"{a}"'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a variable to receive the replaced value.

```
 str = "some_word"
 str = replace(old_chars, new_chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> strr = "some_word"
>>> strr = f'"{strr}"'
>>> print(strr)
"some_word"
```

Comment: What if the user doesn't need to replace the entire string, but only a part of it? This can't work and the solution is too specific from my point of view. Also it only works with new versions of Python